# Laplacian and Dirac Delta function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, dirac-delta-distributions

Although I find it mathematically dubious, we said that $$\Delta \frac{1}{r} ~=~ -4\pi \delta^3({\bf r}).$$ Now, I was wondering is there a similar relation to the delta function if we look at $$\Delta \frac{1}{r^n} ~=~?$$

Comment: Could you give some background as to what you are referring to?

Comment: It's not really that dubious if you define it all in terms of Fourier transforms.

Comment: So is there an explicit formula?

Comment: I am referring to the laplacian of a scalar field $\frac{1}{r^n}$ and was wondering what the result will be.